# Ways to find all function definitions in a elf binary

Tags: elf

Suppose I have a lib xxx.so. So I get all function names and parameters by 
following commnad:

```
readelf -Ws xxx.so  |c++filt
```

It will output following:

```
  711: 00270209    40 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    8 debug_c_tree
  7712: 00270231   128 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    8 pp_c_tree_decl_identifier
  7713: 00270723    90 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    8 pp_c_init_declarator
  7714: 002f546c     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS _edata
  7715: 002f546c     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS __bss_start
  7716: 002fc9e1     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS _end
```

But how can I easily dump all function body like following in a elf binary:

```
debug_c_tree() 
{
  mov eax, edx;
  ....
  ....
}

....
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear: in any context I can think of in which it is easy to find function names and parameters in an `ELF` file, finding function bodies is *easier*.

Comment: @EmployedRussian I have updated my question.

Comment: You don't get parameters with `c++filt`, you get parameter *types*. And for `C` functions, you get *nothing*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can I easily dump all function body

```
objdump -d xxx.so
```

Answer (score 1):

```
objdump -D -z ELFfileName
```

This will disassemble the entire file including all sections and also
space between functions.